# Strange Django behavior with DB insert from separate thread

Tags: python, django

I have a simple test case failing in Django:

Model (app/models.py):

```
from django.db import models
class M(models.Model):
    condition = models.CharField(max_length=80, db_index=True)
```

Test (app/tests.py):

```
from django.test import TestCase
import threading
import time
from app.models import M

def insert():
    time.sleep(0.3)
    ua = M(condition='x')
    ua.save()

class DjangoRaceTest(TestCase):
    def test_parallel(self):
        insert()  # <--- works
        #threading.Thread(target=insert).start()  # <-- fails

        for i in range(10):
            count = M.objects.all()
            if count:
                return True
            time.sleep(0.1)

        assert count
```

The code above passes; but if I comment out the direct call to insert and instead uncomment the thread call, the assertion fails, and I get:

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/threading.py", line 532, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/threading.py", line 484, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/home/jacobsen/testdjango/app/tests.py", line 10, in insert
    ua.save()
  File "/home/jacobsen/dj14/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.4-py2.6.egg/django/db/models/base.py", line 463, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update)
  File "/home/jacobsen/dj14/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.4-py2.6.egg/django/db/models/base.py", line 551, in save_base
    result = manager._insert([self], fields=fields, return_id=update_pk, using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/home/jacobsen/dj14/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.4-py2.6.egg/django/db/models/manager.py", line 203, in _insert
    return insert_query(self.model, objs, fields, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jacobsen/dj14/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.4-py2.6.egg/django/db/models/query.py", line 1576, in insert_query
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/home/jacobsen/dj14/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.4-py2.6.egg/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 910, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/jacobsen/dj14/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.4-py2.6.egg/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 337, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
DatabaseError: no such table: app_m
```

Clearly there is some Django magic failing me here, or ... something?  I've tested this on various combinations of OS X, Ubuntu 10.04, Django 1.2 and 1.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer seems to be that in memory sqlite databases can't be shared across threads.

[This is a bug report from 1.1](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/12118) where a core devs concludes it's not a bug based on [SQLAlchemy's lack of support](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_6/dialects/sqlite.html#threading-behavior) for it (in the absence of other direct info from sqlite references):

> Pysqlite connections do not support being moved between threads,
>   unless the check_same_thread Pysqlite flag is set to False. In
>   addition, when using an in-memory SQLite database, the full database
>   exists only within the scope of a single connection. It is reported
>   that an in-memory database does not support being shared between
>   threads regardless of the check_same_thread flag - which means that a
>   multithreaded application cannot share data from a :memory: database
>   across threads unless access to the connection is limited to a single
>   worker thread which communicates through a queueing mechanism to
>   concurrent threads.